# How to use i18next with KeystoneJS

Tags: i18next, keystonejs

I want to be able to translate labels for models in KeystoneJS.

What is the best strategy to use i18next and keystone?

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Types = keystone.Field.Types;

Driver = new keystone.List('Driver', {
    label: i18n.t("Drivers"),
});
```

Comment: best strategy is to use it. If you run into a particular problem then we can help.

Comment: @harry-moreno my problem is that I need to add translations to strings that are loaded from node_modules updated from npm. How to overwrite these strings without manipulating core Keystonejs module

Comment: well i18next defines a dictionary of scenarios and translations. Then you use these scenario placeholders and the appropriate translation is put in at run-time. So I don't think you can replace string in modules from NPM. Instead you want to use them and use i18next for whatever you display to the end user.